# How to get the convergence radius of the result of Series?

Tags: series-expansion, convergence

The Taylor expansion of function is very useful, but the convergence radius of power series results after Taylor expansion is also important. But the result of `Series` function does not contain the information of convergence region. What should I do to get the information of convergence region at the same time?

**Examples for testing:**

```
    Series[Power[Log[1-x]^2, (2)^-1]/Sqrt[x],{x,0,5}]
    Series[Tan[x],{x,0,5}]
    Series[Sin[m*x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: For a function that is complex-differentiable in a neighborhood of the center of the series, the radius is the distance from the center to the nearest singularity.  Your first example however is not complex-differentiable at zero, and as a function of a real variable, it is not defined in a neighborhood of `0`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you for your help. Although the post you provided is similar to my question, this post has no adopted answer.

Answer (score 5):

In principle, the formula (for example, see [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence)) $$ \frac 1 R=\limsup_{n->\infty} |a_n|^{\frac 1 n}$$ together with the `SeriesCoefficint` command should do the job for power series. However, there are technical problems with it.

(i)  `Series[Power[Log[1-x]^2, (2)^-1]/Sqrt[x],{x,0,5}]` performs

$$ O\left(x^{11/2}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{x} \sqrt{x^2}}{x}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2} x^{3/2}}{2 x}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2} x^{5/2}}{3 x}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2} x^{7/2}}{4 x}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2} x^{9/2}}{5 x}.$$
This is not a power series. Moreover, the branch cut along the negative ray should be taken into account.

(ii)The complicated formula for `SeriesCoefficient[Tan[x], {x, 0, n}]`
$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{i^{n+1} 2^n \left((-1)^n-1\right) \left(2^{n+1}-1\right) B_{n+1}}{(n+1)!} & n\geq 1
   \\
 0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}$$ (see [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)) is implemented in Mathematica. However, it is difficult to operate with that:

```
a = Assuming[n >= 1,ComplexExpand[Abs[SeriesCoefficient[Tan[x], {x, 0, n}]]]]
(*(1/Sqrt[(((1 + n)!)^2)])2^n Sqrt[(-1 + 2^(1 + n))^2] Sqrt[Im[BernoulliB[1 + n]]^2 + 
Re[BernoulliB[1 + n]]^2] Sqrt[(1 + Cos[(1 + n) \[Pi]])^2 +  Sin[(1 + n) \[Pi]]^2]*)
b = FullSimplify[a, Assumptions -> n >= 1]
(*(2^(1/2 + n) (-1 + 2^(1 + n)) Abs[BernoulliB[1 + n]] Sqrt[ 1 + Cos[(1 + n)\[Pi]]])/Gamma[2 + n]*)
```

and

```
DiscreteMaxLimit[b^(1/n), n -> Infinity]
```

is running without any result during a long time.

(iii) Here I succeed for concrete values of $m$, e.g.

```
a[n_] := SeriesCoefficient[Sin[(3 + I)*x], {x, 0, n}, Assumptions -> n > 0]
DiscreteMaxLimit[(FullSimplify[
Assuming[n >= 1, ComplexExpand[Abs[a[n]]]], 
Assumptions -> n >= 1])^(1/n), n -> Infinity]
(*0*)
```

This means the power series converges for each complex number $x$. It should be noticed that

```
SumConvergence[SeriesCoefficient[Sin[3*x], {x, 0, n}, Assumptions -> n > 0]*x^n, n]
```

returns the input.